# IIS: removing the Server HTTP header without URLScan

Tags: iis, web-server, http

(Windows 2003 R2, IIS 6)

Is there anyway to disable the "Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0" HTTP header that doesn't involve installation or URLScan?  Our initial testing showed some problems with URLScan and one of our web-services, and we'd rather avoid installing an entire tool just to remove one header.

Comment: Well -- you can try [Server Mask](http://www.port80software.com/products/servermask/) .. or write your own custom ISAPI Filter that will do just that.